# Bootstrap button pop up message

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on my page and I want it to display a pop up box when its clicked however I have tried few things and it doesnt work

I want to make that button to display message when its clicked.

```
<button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreinfo"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>  Find out more</button>

    <div id="moreinfo" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                fds
                </div><!--end of modal header-->

                <div class="modal-content">
                fds
                </div><!--end of modal content-->

                <div class="modal-footer">
                fds
                </div><!--end of modal footer-->

            </div><!--end of modal content-->

        </div><!--end of modal dialog-->

    </div><!--en dof more info div-->
```

With this code all I get is the screen fades out when the button is clicked but it doesnt display anything.

I have got the following too

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 typos in your code:

1. `<div class="modal dialog">`

   There should not be any space between `modal dialog`. Its one class `modal-dialog`.
2. You are missing `modal-body` inside `modal`. Instead you have used `modal-content` twice. It should have the structure as per [Bootstrap's Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreinfo"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>  Find out more</button>

    <div id="moreinfo" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                fds
                </div><!--end of modal header-->

                <div class="modal-body">
                fds
                </div><!--end of modal body-->

                <div class="modal-footer">
                fds
                </div><!--end of modal footer-->

            </div><!--end of modal content-->

        </div><!--end of modal dialog-->

    </div><!--en dof more info div-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You didnt put hyphen in modal and dilaog , you wrote

```
<div class="modal dialog">
```

but You have to write like this

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
```

just because of hyphen(-) all problem occured

Comment: Always the little things are the problem in programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the Bootstrap popover?
If yes - [here](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo-1) are good and simple example and documentation that exactly represents your needle.

Or you need the button that will call your modal window? If yes - [here](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo) are good example and documentation that also exactly represents your needle.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, however I want to have a pop up box to show up when I click the button. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately i can't understand what you mean under "popup box". I added example for modal window that you probably need but still not sure you need exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is correct the only problem was in this line .

You have to write like that

All modal code is here of your now just copy paste it and save your time :) cheers

```
<div id="moreinfo" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div><!--end of modal header-->
          <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div><!--end of modal footer-->
    </div><!--end of modal content-->
  </div><!--end of modal dialog-->
</div><!--en dof more info div-->
```